# MySQL Float Approximation and Precision

Tags: mysql

I've got a column set as a `FLOAT(32,11)` and I'm getting some odd results with storing values. Now I know that floats are only an approximation however this seems to be a horrible approximation especially with the given precision.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (a FLOAT(32,11));
mysql> INSERT INTO test (a) VALUES (300000.08);
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+--------------------+
| a                  |
+--------------------+
| 300000.09375000000 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Seems odd that it isn't using all the available precision. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

MySQL Version 5.1.73 on CentOS

Comment: You're probably running in a storage limitation. if you insert `30,000.08` (small by  factor of 10), you get `30,000.08007812500` back out.

Comment: @Sajad Please do not hijack other people's questions !

Comment: @LorenzMeyer you right, sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FLOAT` is [single-precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). This only has 24 bits of mantissa. This isn't enough to hold 8 decimal digits accurately, so you get an error in the lowest digit.

If you use `DOUBLE` instead of `FLOAT`, you get a more accurate result.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (a DOUBLE(32,11));    
mysql> INSERT INTO test (a) VALUES (300000.08);    
mysql> select * from test;
+--------------------+
| a                  |
+--------------------+
| 300000.08000000002 |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the loss of precision is generated, but, quoting from the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html):

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies.

So, the alternative I suggest you is: Use `DECIMAL` instead of `FLOAT` (or `DOUBLE`) to enforce precission