# Show decimals entered as it is in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in MySQL 'float'. And iam trying to insert a float value '1.1'. Its fine. its storing in MySQL as 1.1, which is fine. But when I am trying to get the value in PHP, the value is showing as '1.100000023841858'.I need to show the figures as it is.

If I use varchar then I cannot sort because Lets say my values are 1.1, 2.1 and 10.1, then the records will sort as 1.1, 10.1 and 2.1, which is incorrect while sorting.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Moral: don't use floats as serial numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Float Approximation and Precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335901/mysql-float-approximation-and-precision)

Comment: If by serial number you mean version number, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295871/how-to-store-version-number-in-mysql-database

Comment: I will check the same.